# Build failed for Visual Studio for MAC after updating to .net version 6

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin

** /Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/MonoBundle/MSBuild/Current/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5):
Error MSB3971: The reference assemblies for ".NETFramework,Version=v6.0" were not found. You might be using an older .NET SDK to target .NET 5.0 or higher. Update Visual Studio and/or your .NET SDK. (MSB3971) **

Although I have udpated the visual studio but its trowing same error again.

Comment: My guess is that you have .NET 6.0.300 or higher and no lower versions. When you have a classic Xamarin project it cannot use .NET 6.0.300 since the msbuild version does not support it so it downgrades. If you install .NET 6.0.10x SDK then that may solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Install .NET 6.0.10x SDK. That will solve the problem.

Comment: Posting Matt's suggestion since that fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is what solved the issue for me:

1. Go to your Solution properties
2. Under Build General, uncheck "Use MSBuild on Mono"
   [image]

Comment: For me it wasn't checked but my .csproj had `<BuildWithMSBuildOnMono>true</BuildWithMSBuildOnMono>` and removing it fixed this.